# Youtube views using the Flash API

Tags: flash, api, youtube, youtube-api

I have a very simple question. Does youtube count "views" if put a YT video into a swf, using their Flash API? I can't seem to find anyplace that explains how views are counted.

Answer (score 0):

**Generally yes, but user have to press YouTube play button.**

It's like on normal website. If auto-play is enabled views do not count. It will be to easy to make views counter BOT.

**More info:**
http://knol.google.com/k/alec-go/youtube-player-apis-when-will-a-view/2vd5zn6va2fqd/13#